# Is it possible to introduce more values to a materialized Akka Source in javadsl?

Tags: akka, akka-stream

I am trying to setup a stream with Akka's javadsl which handles the processing of new files in a folder. My question is:

Should I re-run the RunnableFlow every time a new file is introduced,

or is it possible to keep a RunnableFlow running indefinitaly while the stream is waiting for new files to be introduced to the Source of said Flow?

My source as it is now:

```
Queue<Path> esbList = new Queue<>();
final Source<Path, BoxedUnit> pathSource = Source.from(esbList);
```

The Queue is a simple iterable queue

Comment: This is a potential duplicate of an answer I previously gave on having a dynamic (unbounded) source.  Take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29072963/how-to-add-elements-to-source-dynamically/29077212#29077212

Comment: I agree, the questions are very much alike. Is your answer to that question also applicable in a javadsl manner?

Comment: The code I wrote there "should" be able to be ported over to java.  I think the underlying concept of using an actor as the source should still work though I have not tried it myself.

Comment: I'll see if I can port it. If so, i'll close this question, if not, I'd like to keep it open, altered to specify javadsl. Thanks for your input!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out it is not possible to add elements to a Source which has been created from a collection like a queue. The available elements in the collection will be passed during the materialization of the stream and the stream will be completed when these elements are processed.

As cmbaxter mentions creating a Source in which elements can be added after materialization is possible by creating a Source via an ActorPublisher.

Akka documentation:

http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-stream-and-http-experimental/1.0-RC3/java/stream-integrations.html#ActorPublisher

Related question:

[How to add elements to Source dynamically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29072963/how-to-add-elements-to-source-dynamically/29077212#29077212)