# How to create a Source that can receive elements later via a method call?

Tags: scala, akka, akka-stream, akka-http

I would like to create a `Source` and later push elements on it, like in:

```
val src = ... // create the Source here
// and then, do something like this
pushElement(x1, src)
pushElement(x2, src)
```

What is the recommended way to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: This might be the same as: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29072963/how-to-add-elements-to-source-dynamically/29077212#29077212

Comment: @cmbaxter Indeed. Although I was thinking more in a way to just feed the stream by sending messages to some actor, without instantiating or having  a class for this actor. I believe that it's possible with the `Source.actorRef` functionality, as I see in the post you linked and here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30785011/accessing-the-underlying-actorref-of-an-akka-stream-source-created-by-source-act. Thanks a lot)

Comment: You may also find this answer helpful:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40345697/how-to-use-akka-http-client-websocket-send-message/44605821#44605821

Answer (score 103, accepted):

There are three ways this can be achieved:

**1. Post Materialization with SourceQueue**

You can use `Source.queue` that materializes the Flow into a `SourceQueue`:

```
case class Weather(zipCode : String, temperature : Double, raining : Boolean)

val bufferSize = 100

//if the buffer fills up then this strategy drops the oldest elements
//upon the arrival of a new element.
val overflowStrategy = akka.stream.OverflowStrategy.dropHead

val queue = Source.queue(bufferSize, overflowStrategy)
                  .filter(!_.raining)
                  .to(Sink foreach println)
                  .run() // in order to "keep" the queue Materialized value instead of the Sink's

queue offer Weather("02139", 32.0, true)
```

**2. Post Materialization with Actor**

There is a similar question and answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30785011/accessing-the-underlying-actorref-of-an-akka-stream-source-created-by-source-act), the gist being that you materialize the stream as an ActorRef and send messages to that ref:

```
val ref = Source.actorRef[Weather](Int.MaxValue, fail)
                .filter(!_.raining)
                .to(Sink foreach println )
                .run() // in order to "keep" the ref Materialized value instead of the Sink's

ref ! Weather("02139", 32.0, true)
```

**3. Pre Materialization with Actor**

Similarly, you could explicitly create an Actor that contains a message buffer, use that Actor to create a Source, and then send that Actor messages as described in the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33382895/idiomatic-way-to-use-spark-dstream-as-source-for-an-akka-stream/33392445#33392445):

```
object WeatherForwarder {
  def props : Props = Props[WeatherForwarder]
}

//see provided link for example definition
class WeatherForwarder extends Actor {...}

val actorRef = actorSystem actorOf WeatherForwarder.props 

//note the stream has not been instatiated yet
actorRef ! Weather("02139", 32.0, true) 

//stream already has 1 Weather value to process which is sitting in the 
//ActorRef's internal buffer
val stream = Source(ActorPublisher[Weather](actorRef)).runWith{...}
```

Comment: @Loic I did not get from your comment that "prematerialization with queue" would be a fourth possible solution. It is. I found this good: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37113877/how-can-i-use-and-return-source-queue-to-caller-without-materializing-it/37117205#37117205

Comment: @akauppi In the link you posted if you `mapMaterializedValue` it will create another source. He use a Future to get the queue of the source he wants to return.

Comment: Question: is that possible when I call queue.complete() , after the upstream emit to sink, I start to push to queue again ?

Comment: @zt1983811 I have never attempted the use case you specified.

Comment: How can I do this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44316740/akka-stream-sliding-window-to-control-reduce-emit-to-sink/44317588?noredirect=1#comment75647475_44317588

Comment: @akauppi Because I also use queue to emit the data to source but I can not do reduce once I use this.

Comment: @akauppi I have create a test project in gitlab, and I put the detail explaination on the readme for this project, also create the test run you can run with spring boot. Please help me thanks so much https://gitlab.com/tongzhougit/Demo-akka-stream-reduce-question

Answer (score 19):

Since Akka 2.5 `Source` has a [`preMaterialize`](https://doc.akka.io/api/akka/2.5/akka/stream/javadsl/Source.html#preMaterialize(materializer:akka.stream.Materializer):akka.japi.Pair[Mat@scala.annotation.unchecked.uncheckedVariance,akka.stream.javadsl.Source[Out@scala.annotation.unchecked.uncheckedVariance,akka.NotUsed]]) method.

According to the [documentation](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.5.25/stream/stream-flows-and-basics.html#source-pre-materialization), this looks like the indicated way to do what you ask:

> There are situations in which you require a `Source` materialized value before the `Source` gets hooked up to the rest of the graph. This is particularly useful in the case of “materialized value powered” Sources, like `Source.queue`, `Source.actorRef` or `Source.maybe`.

Below an example on how this would be with a `SourceQueue`. Elements are pushed to the queue before and after materialization, as well as from within the `Flow`:

```
import akka.actor.ActorSystem
import akka.stream.scaladsl._
import akka.stream.{ActorMaterializer, OverflowStrategy}

implicit val system = ActorSystem("QuickStart")
implicit val materializer = ActorMaterializer()


val sourceDecl = Source.queue[String](bufferSize = 2, OverflowStrategy.backpressure)
val (sourceMat, source) = sourceDecl.preMaterialize()

// Adding element before actual materialization
sourceMat.offer("pre materialization element")

val flow = Flow[String].map { e =>
  if(!e.contains("new")) {
    // Adding elements from within the flow
    sourceMat.offer("new element generated inside the flow")
  }
  s"Processing $e"
}

// Actually materializing with `run`
source.via(flow).to(Sink.foreach(println)).run()

// Adding element after materialization
sourceMat.offer("post materialization element")
```

Output:

```
Processing pre materialization element
Processing post materialization element
Processing new element generated inside the flow
Processing new element generated inside the flow
```

Comment: I've been struggling to create a pre and post materialization around a queue. This answer is very useful. Thanks for such explanation.

Comment: Awesome, this is just what I was looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

After playing around and looking for a good solution to this I came across this solution which is clean, simple, and works both pre and post materialization.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/32553913/6791842

```
  val (ref: ActorRef, publisher: Publisher[Int]) =
    Source.actorRef[Int](bufferSize = 1000, OverflowStrategy.fail)
      .toMat(Sink.asPublisher(true))(Keep.both).run()

  ref ! 1 //before

  val source = Source.fromPublisher(publisher)

  ref ! 2 //before
  Thread.sleep(1000)
  ref ! 3 //before

  source.runForeach(println)

  ref ! 4 //after
  Thread.sleep(1000)
  ref ! 5 //after
```

Output:

```
1
2
3
4
5
```