# Akka Flow hangs when making http requests via connection pool

Tags: scala, akka, akka-stream, akka-http

I'm using Akka 2.4.4 and trying to move from Apache HttpAsyncClient (unsuccessfully).

Below is simplified version of code that I use in my project.

The problem is that it hangs if I send more than 1-3 requests to the flow. So far after 6 hours of debugging I couldn't even locate the problem. I don't see exceptions, error logs, events in `Decider`. NOTHING :)

I tried reducing `connection-timeout` setting to 1s thinking that maybe it's waiting for response from the server but it didn't help.

What am I doing wrong ?

```
import akka.actor.ActorSystem
import akka.http.scaladsl.Http
import akka.http.scaladsl.model.headers.Referer
import akka.http.scaladsl.model.{HttpRequest, HttpResponse}
import akka.http.scaladsl.settings.ConnectionPoolSettings
import akka.stream.Supervision.Decider
import akka.stream.scaladsl.{Sink, Source}
import akka.stream.{ActorAttributes, Supervision}
import com.typesafe.config.ConfigFactory

import scala.collection.immutable.{Seq => imSeq}
import scala.concurrent.{Await, Future}
import scala.concurrent.duration.Duration
import scala.util.Try

object Main {

  implicit val system = ActorSystem("root")
  implicit val executor = system.dispatcher
  val config = ConfigFactory.load()

  private val baseDomain = "www.google.com"
  private val poolClientFlow = Http()(system).cachedHostConnectionPool[Any](baseDomain, 80, ConnectionPoolSettings(config))

  private val decider: Decider = {
    case ex =>
      ex.printStackTrace()
      Supervision.Stop
  }

  private def sendMultipleRequests[T](items: Seq[(HttpRequest, T)]): Future[Seq[(Try[HttpResponse], T)]] =

    Source.fromIterator(() => items.toIterator)
      .via(poolClientFlow)
      .log("Logger")(log = myAdapter)
      .recoverWith {
        case ex =>
          println(ex)
          null
      }
      .withAttributes(ActorAttributes.supervisionStrategy(decider))
      .runWith(Sink.seq)
      .map { v =>
        println(s"Got ${v.length} responses in Flow")
        v.asInstanceOf[Seq[(Try[HttpResponse], T)]]
      }

  def main(args: Array[String]) {

    val headers = imSeq(Referer("https://www.google.com/"))
    val reqPair = HttpRequest(uri = "/intl/en/policies/privacy").withHeaders(headers) -> "some req ID"
    val requests = List.fill(10)(reqPair)
    val qwe = sendMultipleRequests(requests).map { case responses =>
      println(s"Got ${responses.length} responses")

      system.terminate()
    }

    Await.ready(system.whenTerminated, Duration.Inf)
  }
}
```

Also what's up with [proxy support](https://github.com/akka/akka/blob/master/akka-http-core/src/main/resources/reference.conf#L146-L150) ? Doesn't seem to work for me either.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to consume the body of the response fully so that the connection is made available for subsequent requests.  If you don't care about the response entity at all, then you can just drain it to a `Sink.ignore`, something like this:

```
resp.entity.dataBytes.runWith(Sink.ignore)
```

By the default config, when using a host connection pool, the max connections is set to 4.  Each pool has it's own queue where requests wait until one of the open connections becomes available.  If that queue ever goes over 32 (default config, can be changed, must be a power of 2) then yo will start seeing failures.  In your case, you only do 10 requests, so you don't hit that limit.  But by not consuming the response entity you don't free up the connection and everything else just queues in behind, waiting for the connections to free up.

Comment: I actually tried that and it didn't help. Maybe I placed it in wrong place. Could you please take a look at self-contained project I created ? https://github.com/cppexpert/akka_flow_freezing

Comment: Ya, that's the problem.  You are trying to sequence the results of 10 futures and then reading the body.  The problem there is that in order to call map on `sequence`, all 10 futures must have been completed and only the first 4 will be and those first 4 are blocking the other 6.  Push the response reading code up further and that will fix your issue.

Comment: Could you demonstrate how you'd move response reading code up ? I tried few things and it's still waiting for futures to be finished in bulk. Even in my example should `parseResponse` be called asynchronously before on each response BEFORE it's passed to Future.sequence ? Perhaps I could move to to `toMat` of queue but then I won't be able to use it for parsing different responses. Packing lamba along with `(Any, Promise[..])` for every request seems too ugly to me.

Comment: Here is "ugly" - https://github.com/akka/akka/issues/20460#issuecomment-217727754

Comment: I won't be able to do this today, but I'll fork your repo and submit a pull request early AM tomorrow.