# Akka http client Exceptions handling (Java)

Tags: java, exception, akka, akka-http

I am trying to to create http client, using akka http. I have already founded interesting solution which I want to use: [How to properly call Akka HTTP client for multiple (10k - 100k) requests?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34293113/how-to-properly-call-akka-http-client-for-multiple-10k-100k-requests)
But I can't find any way to get exeptions from this constraction

```
Source.from(() -> httpRequests.iterator())
                .via(connectionFlow)
                .runForeach((HttpResponse response) -> onComplete.accept(response), materializer);
```

of cource I can log them, but I need some custom exceptions processing whith try-catch construction.
Probably I need to use recoverWith method, but I use Java not Scala, and I am not sure hov to use this method correctly. This signature is 
`recoverWith[T >: Out](pf: PartialFunction[Throwable, _ <: Graph[SourceShape[T], NotUsed]]): Source[T, Mat @uncheckedVariance]`
and I am not sure which types and which Graph implementation use here.
For single request I use this construction:

```
CompletionStage<HttpResponse> future = Http.get(actorSystem).singleRequest(httpRequest, materializer);
    future.whenComplete((HttpResponse response, Throwable failure) -> onComplete.accept(failure, response));
```

Please help me if there is some way to process many requests with exeptions handling using akka-http.