# How can I use and return Source queue to caller without materializing it?

Tags: scala, akka, akka-stream

I'm trying to use new Akka streams and wonder how I can use and return Source queue to caller without materializing it in my code ?

Imagine we have library that makes number of async calls and returns results via `Source`. Function looks like this

```
def findArticlesByTitle(text: String): Source[String, SourceQueue[String]] = {

  val source = Source.queue[String](100, backpressure)

  source.mapMaterializedValue { case queue =>

    val url = s"http://.....&term=$text"
    httpclient.get(url).map(httpResponseToSprayJson[SearchResponse]).map { v =>
      v.idlist.foreach { id =>
        queue.offer(id)
      }

      queue.complete()
    }
  }

  source
}
```

and caller might use it like this

```
// There is implicit ActorMaterializer somewhere
val stream = plugin.findArticlesByTitle(title)
val results = stream.runFold(List[String]())((result, article) => article :: result)
```

When I run this code within `mapMaterializedValue` is never executed.

I can't understand why I don't have access to instance of `SourceQueue` if it should be up to caller to decide how to materialize the source.

How should I implement this ?

Comment: What is the reason for populating the queue when the value is materialized, instead of iterating over the results and generating the source from this iterable, something like `val ids: Iterable[String] = httpclient.get(url).map(…); val source = Source.from(ids)`?

Comment: Use of concrete collection diminishes idea of `Source` that assumes arrival of objects some time later in time. Imagine library function will return trillion of documents. Client should be able to process them as they come.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your code example you're returning source instead of the return value of `source.mapMaterializedValue` (the method call doesn't mutate the Source object).

Comment: BTW, in your code example you're returing `source` instead of the return value of `source.mapMaterializedValue` (the method call doesn't mutate the `Source` object). Not sure if this is the same in your actual code.

Comment: It was  `mapMaterializedValue`. Thank you! I've updated your answer with what you told me in comment so I can accept it.