# How to put some data into stream from outside?

Tags: scala, tcp, akka-stream

Situation: have a few clients that want to join to server. AkkaStreamServerTCP (actor) manages connections and creates handlers (TcpSession, actor) for each connection. Due GraphStage i can create a really complicated logic for managing data, for example, can add BidiFlow for coding data. 
But i didn't understand how I can put bunch of data, that i receive from another actor, into stream? 
For example, in [akka.io.Tcp](http://doc.akka.io/api/akka/2.4/?_ga=1.87612944.947256036.1469328127#akka.io.Tcp$) we have Events and Commands, such as Write, Read. But what about streams?

Any help would be appreciated!

[image]

Comment: Does this question answer yours: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30964824/how-to-create-a-source-that-can-receive-elements-later-via-a-method-call/33415214#33415214

Comment: @RamonJRomeroyVigil didn't try it yet, but looks like this answer solves my problem. Thanks.