# How to use Akka-HTTP client websocket send message

Tags: scala, akka-stream, akka-http

I'm trying client-side websocket by following doc at [webSocketClientFlow](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.4/scala/http/client-side/websocket-support.html#webSocketClientFlow).

sample code is:

```
import akka.actor.ActorSystem
import akka.Done
import akka.http.scaladsl.Http
import akka.stream.ActorMaterializer
import akka.stream.scaladsl._
import akka.http.scaladsl.model._
import akka.http.scaladsl.model.ws._

import scala.concurrent.Future

object WebSocketClientFlow {
  def main(args: Array[String]) = {
    implicit val system = ActorSystem()
    implicit val materializer = ActorMaterializer()
    import system.dispatcher

    // Future[Done] is the materialized value of Sink.foreach,
    // emitted when the stream completes
    val incoming: Sink[Message, Future[Done]] =
      Sink.foreach[Message] {
        case message: TextMessage.Strict =>
          println(message.text)
      }

    // send this as a message over the WebSocket
    val outgoing = Source.single(TextMessage("hello world!"))

    // flow to use (note: not re-usable!)
    val webSocketFlow = Http().webSocketClientFlow(WebSocketRequest("ws://echo.websocket.org"))

    // the materialized value is a tuple with
    // upgradeResponse is a Future[WebSocketUpgradeResponse] that
    // completes or fails when the connection succeeds or fails
    // and closed is a Future[Done] with the stream completion from the incoming sink
    val (upgradeResponse, closed) =
      outgoing
        .viaMat(webSocketFlow)(Keep.right) // keep the materialized Future[WebSocketUpgradeResponse]
        .toMat(incoming)(Keep.both) // also keep the Future[Done]
        .run()

    // just like a regular http request we can access response status which is available via upgrade.response.status
    // status code 101 (Switching Protocols) indicates that server support WebSockets
    val connected = upgradeResponse.flatMap { upgrade =>
      if (upgrade.response.status == StatusCodes.SwitchingProtocols) {
        Future.successful(Done)
      } else {
        throw new RuntimeException(s"Connection failed: ${upgrade.response.status}")
      }
    }

    // in a real application you would not side effect here
    connected.onComplete(println)
    closed.foreach(_ => println("closed"))
  }
}
```

after had connection upgraded, how to use the `connection` send message to websocket server side?

I noticed from the doc:

> The Flow that is returned by this method can only be materialized once. For each request a new flow must be acquired by calling the method again.

still confused, why we need construct the flow many times since an upgraded connection alrady ready.

Comment: Sorry, not really clear what you're asking. You send messages over a websockets connection by pushing messages into the respective stream; in your particular case only one message (`TextMessage("hello world!")`) will be sent to the server, and the outgoing stream will be closed after that. The incoming stream (created out of `Sink.foreach`) will continue to receive messages until the server closes the stream or until a receive timeout kicks in. You have to construct an appropriate `Source`, maybe based on actors, if you want to control what you send in a more complex way.

Comment: @VladimirMatveev thanks for reminding. I think I had a misunderstanding on how akka-http works, going to read docs in depth. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 15):

You can create an actor based source and send new messages over the established websocket connection.

```
    val req = WebSocketRequest(uri = "ws://127.0.0.1/ws")
    val webSocketFlow = Http().webSocketClientFlow(req)

    val messageSource: Source[Message, ActorRef] = 
         Source.actorRef[TextMessage.Strict](bufferSize = 10, OverflowStrategy.fail)

    val messageSink: Sink[Message, NotUsed] =
        Flow[Message]
            .map(message => println(s"Received text message: [$message]"))
            .to(Sink.ignore)

    val ((ws, upgradeResponse), closed) =
        messageSource
            .viaMat(webSocketFlow)(Keep.both)
            .toMat(messageSink)(Keep.both)
            .run()

    val connected = upgradeResponse.flatMap { upgrade =>
        if (upgrade.response.status == StatusCodes.SwitchingProtocols) {
            Future.successful(Done)
        } else {
            throw new RuntimeException(s"Connection failed: ${upgrade.response.status}")
        }
    }

    ws ! TextMessage.Strict("Hello World")
    ws ! TextMessage.Strict("Hi")
    ws ! TextMessage.Strict("Yay!")
```

`

Comment: it helped me alot can you please look into my question its related to your code thanks it would be of great help here is the link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63505847/how-to-use-flow-map-in-akka-client-side-websocket-in-akka-streams