# Akka stream sliding window to control reduce emit to sink by SourceQueue

Tags: java, streaming, akka, akka-stream

**Update** : I put my question in [test project](https://gitlab.com/tongzhougit/Demo-akka-stream-reduce-question)  to explain what I mean in detail

=====================================================================

I have Akka source that contiune read from database table, and groupby some key then reduce it. However it seems after I apply reduce function, the data never send to sink, it will contiune reduce since upstream always have data coming.

I read some post, and tried groupedWithin and sliding, but it does not work as I thought, it only group the message to larger part but never make the upstream pause and emit to sink. Following is the code in Akka stream 2.5.2

The Source reduce code:

```
source = source
  .groupedWithin(100, FiniteDuration.apply(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS))
  .sliding(3, 1)
  .mapConcat(i -> i)
  .mapConcat(i -> i)
  .groupBy(2000000, i -> i.getEntityName())
  .map(i -> new Pair<>(i.getEntityName(), i))
  .reduce((l, r) ->{ l.second().setAction(r.second().getAction() + l.second().getAction()); return l;})
  .map(i -> i.second())
  .mergeSubstreams();
```

The Sink and run:

```
Sink<Object, CompletionStage<Done>> sink = 
        Sink.foreach(i -> System.out.println(i))
final RunnableGraph<SourceQueueWithComplete<Object>> run = source.toMat(sink, Keep.left());
run.run(materIalizer);
```

I have also tried .takeWhile(predicated); I use timer to switch predicated value true and false, but it seems it will only take the first switch to false, when I switch back to true it is not restart upstream.

Please help me thanks in advance!

=================================================

**Update for**

> information about the type of elements

Add what I want:
I have class call `SystemCodeTracking` contains 2 attributes `(id, entityName)`

I will have list of object: `(1, "table1"), (2, "table2"), (3, "table3"),(4, "table1"),(5, "table3")`

I would like to groupBy entityName then sum the id , therefore, the result I would like to see is following

```
("table1" 1+4),("table3", 3+5),("table2", 2)
```

The code I am doing now is following

```
source
.groupBy(2000000, systemCodeTracking -> systemCodeTracking.getEntityName)
.map(systemCodeTracking -> new Pair<String, Integer>(systemCodeTracking.getEntityName, SystemCodeTracking.getId()))
.scan(....)
```

my question right now is more on how to build scan inital state
should I do ?

```
scan(new Pair<>("", 0), (first, second) -> first.setId(first.getId() + second.getId()))
```

Comment: Why do you put `mapConcat` after your grouping flows?

Comment: Because groupedWithin and sliding will give me a List of object but I only need reduce it one by one. Should I reduce the whole list?

Comment: Yes. You should use one of the two (sliding or groupedWithin), and then reduce each list element. I believe what you really want is groupedWithin, it is exactly a time window (with max size).

Comment: @Cyrille Could you show me how to do it? since once I use groupedWithin it will return me List<SourceQueue>, I can not apply reduce function if I do not do mapCancat .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So what you want, if I understand everything well is:

- first, group by id
- then group by time window, and inside this time window, sum all the `systemCodeTracking.getId()`

For the first part, you'll need `groupBy`. For the second part `groupedWithin`. However, they do not work the same: the first one will give you subflows, while the second one will give you a flow of lists.

Therefore, we will have to handle them differently.

First, let's write a reducer for your lists:

```
private SystemCodeTracking reduceList(List<SystemCodeTracking> list) throws Exception {
    if (list.isEmpty()) {
        throw new Exception();
    } else {
        SystemCodeTracking building = list.get(0);
        building.setId(0L);
        list.forEach(next -> building.setId(building.getId() + next.getId()));
        return building;
    }
}
```

So for each element in the list, we increment the `building.id` to get the value we want when the whole list has been traversed.

Now you just need to do

```
Source<SystemCodeTracking, SourceQueueWithComplete<SystemCodeTracking>> loggedSource = source
    .groupBy(20000, SystemCodeTracking::getEntityName) // group by name
    .groupedWithin(100, FiniteDuration.create(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS)   // for a given name, group by time window (or by packs of 100)
    .filterNot(List::isEmpty)                          // remove empty elements from the flow (if no element has passed in the last second, to avoid error in reducer)
    .map(this::reduceList)                             // reduce each list to sum the ids
    .log("====== doing reduceing ")                    // log each passing element using akka logger, rather than `System.out.println`
    .mergeSubstreams()                                 // merge back all elements with different names
```

Comment: Once again, sorry about the java style, I'm really more used to scala code.

Comment: @Cynille Really appreciate your answer it works great. I did a little fix on groupedWithin in more java style ;-). Please accept it and I will accept this answer too.. The only thing is that it seems I can not use native reduce function to achieve this I guess. But anyway  Thank you once again !

Comment: @Cynille Why reject? .groupedWithin(100, sec) does not complie in java, it should be this .groupedWithin(100, FiniteDuration.create(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS)) I think.

Comment: Sorry. I thought it was ok (and cleaner) defining my window in a variable before. I wasn't able to un-reject the edit :-(