# How to send elements to a Source.actorRef or a Source.queue in Java

Tags: java, akka, akka-stream, akka-http

I'm currently working with Akka Streams (in Java) for a personal project and I'm having a hard time understanding how to send element to a `Source`.

The idea is to use a WebSocket to push content into the user's web browser. I've managed to use Akka Streams to create a request-response system, following the Akka HTTP documentation, but this is not what I want to do.

Looking into the Akka Streams documentation, I saw that there is `Source.queue` and `Source.actorRef`. But I don't understand how to put an element into the `Source`. `Source.queue` and `Source.actorRef` return a `Source`, which doesn't have the method `offer` (for `Source.queue`) or `tell` (for `Source.actorRef`).

My question is: how do I get the `ActorRef` for the `Source` created by `Source.actorRef` or the `SourceQueueWithComplete` for a `Source` created with `Source.queue`, to be able to send elements to my `Source`?

I searched the various Akka documentation but found no method to do that. And the majority of the code I found on the Internet is written in Scala, which doesn't seem to have the same problem.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create a Source that can receive elements later via a method call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30964824/how-to-create-a-source-that-can-receive-elements-later-via-a-method-call)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The actor and queue from `Source.actorRef` and `Source.queue`, respectively, are the [materialized values](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.5/java/stream/stream-quickstart.html#materialized-values) of those sources, meaning that they can be obtained only if the stream is running. For example:

```java
final ActorRef actor =
  Source.actorRef(Integer.MAX_VALUE, OverflowStrategy.fail())
        .to(Sink.foreach(m -> System.out.println(m)))
        .run(materializer);

actor.tell("do something", ActorRef.noSender());
```

It's no different in Scala:

```scala
implicit val materializer = ActorMaterializer()

val actor =
  Source.actorRef(Int.MaxValue, OverflowStrategy.fail)
        .to(Sink.foreach(println))
        .run()

actor ! "do something"
```

Comment: As an addition to this answer, the relevant documentation on akka.io can be found here, which may not be completely obvious to find: https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.5.3/scala/stream/stream-integrations.html